# Unable to download PDFs with Perl and LWP

Tags: perl, pdf, lwp

I'm trying to use LWP::Simple in Perl to download a number of PDF documents from the United Nations website (Security Council resolutions, etc.). Yet instead of returning PDFs, I am receiving an HTML error page. Consider this very simple example:

```
use LWP::Simple;
use strict;

my $url = 'https://documents-dds-ny.un.org/doc/UNDOC/GEN/N16/100/02/PDF/N1610002.pdf';
my $file = 'test.pdf';
getstore($url, $file);
```

If I then look at the contents of "test.pdf", I find that they are an HTML page.

I have also tried a number of tricks with LWP::UserAgent and even with cURL, but with no success. Any ideas?

Comment: You get also  the error message if you are trying to access this link directly with a browser. Thus there is some authentication, cookie, referer or whatever needed additionally to the link.

Comment: It's a bit hit and miss with the browser: the majority of times when I paste the path into the browser, the PDF loads up correctly. Sometimes it gives the HTML error page, but not in most cases.

Comment: Re "*the majority of times when I paste the path into the browser, the PDF loads up correctly*", Then, the majority of the time, you had previously visited the main site first. The download site expects cookies set by the main site.

Comment: Yes, you are probably both right. I had been assuming it was temporary server glitches, but the cookies make sense. I will test with HTTP::Cookies and see what I find! Thanks, @SteffenUllrich and ikegami !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @SteffenUllrich and @ ikegami for putting me on the right track!

It is indeed a cookie issue. The fix? Open a cookie jar, access the homepage of the site first, then access the PDF once a cookie has been stored in the jar.

This can be done without using HTTP::Cookies. We need to use LWP::UserAgent instead of LWP::Simple, however.

Minimal working example below:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use LWP::UserAgent;

my $homeUrl       = "https://documents.un.org/prod/ods.nsf/home.xsp"; 
my $pdfUrl        = "https://documents-dds-ny.un.org/doc/UNDOC/GEN/N16/100/02/PDF/N1610002.pdf";
my $pdfOutputName = "test.pdf"; 

my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new( cookie_jar => { } );

my $resp;

$resp = $browser->get( $homeUrl );
die $resp->status_line unless $resp->is_success;

$resp = $browser->get( $pdfUrl, ':content_file' => $pdfOutputName );
die $resp->status_line unless $resp->is_success;
```

This will produce a complete PDF file.

Comment: There's no need to store the home page; just `$browser->get($homeUrl)` will do fine. And `$homeContents` etc. are `HTTP::Response` objects, not "contents", and you really should test them for success: `my $res = $browser->get($url); die $res->status_line unless $res->is_success;`

Comment: You misunderstood my meaning. I've modified your code to demonstrate.